# Trying to open new window using angular 7 (cdkPortal) application, is working fine with chrome, but on edge

Tags: angular, angular7

Trying to open a new window using angular 7 (cdkPortal) application, is working fine with chrome, but on edge, HTML content is not showing on newly opened window.

I am trying with below example, it looks fine with chrome but not in IE Edge:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-open-window

Below is my polyfills.ts files:

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'url-search-params-polyfill';

/**
 * If the application will be indexed by Google Search, the following is required.
 * Googlebot uses a renderer based on Chrome 41.
 * https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/rendering
 **/
import 'core-js/es7/array';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

// (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
// (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
// (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

/*
* in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
* with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
*/
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.


/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */

// Add global to window, assigning the value of window itself.
(window as any).global = window;

/**
 * Fix for ngx-chart to work on ie11
 */
if ( typeof SVGElement.prototype.contains === 'undefined' ) {
    SVGElement.prototype.contains = HTMLDivElement.prototype.contains;
}
```

Comment: Share the polyfills file of yours?

Comment: getting error on IE : ERROR

Error: TypeError: Invalid argument

Comment: Can you post the polyfills.ts?

Answer (score 0):

As per the sample you provided in stackblitz you are using angular version 7 which I assume it is fairly new. In order to IE support newer versions of angular you need to go into `polyfills.ts` (in the src folder by default) and just **uncomment** the following imports:

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
```